# How to add react-router to preact app from preact-cli

Tags: react-router, react-router-dom, preact, preact-cli

I created a Preact app using the preact-cli, and need to add `react-router-dom` to my project for routing. How can I add react-router to the project without ejecting the app, in order to install the router library?

I've seen options for adding webpack, but that' requires ejecting the app.

I added `"preact-compat": "^3.19.0",` to my package.json in the project, but not sure how to either add webpack or import the necessary react-router imports:

`import {BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Switch, NavLink} from 'react-router-dom';`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Was able to get this working with import of `import {BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Switch, NavLink} from 'react-router-dom';` and `yarn build` then `yarn-serve`

Answer (score 0):

> but that' requires ejecting the app

There is no way to "eject" from `preact-cli`. That isn't functionality that exists, so I'm a bit confused on what it is that you're referring to.

We make the entire config available to you through [your `preact.config.js`](https://github.com/preactjs/preact-cli#webpack). With this, you can configure absolutely any part of the Webpack config that you'd like, and only those bits. You don't need to do anything like CRA's eject, where you have to now own the entire config yourself. You can edit the pieces you want, and leave everything else out of site & out of mind.

> I've seen options for adding webpack

`preact-cli` uses Webpack for bundling, it's the fundamental underlying tool. There's no way to use it without Webpack, so this doesn't make much sense.

> I added `"preact-compat": "^3.19.0"`

Remove this. `preact-cli` already adds compat, and does it from the correct source.

If you read [the docs for `preact-compat`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/preact-compat), you'll see it's only for Preact 8.x and prior, which is a few years out-of-date at this point. The correct compat package for v10+ is `preact/compat`. We set this up for you already in `preact-cli` though, so nothing you need to do yourself.

Why do you think you need to do any configuration just to import the library? Did you run into any errors, or maybe docs that are confusing/misworded? Just ran a test with v6, should work out-of-the-box after you swap it in for `preact-router` (assuming you've set up a `preact-cli` project using one of our templates)

Comment: My app was originally built with `create-react-app`. I need to create it with Preact now, and I created the app with the preact cli and default template. I brought all my components over to the new Preact app, but I'm confused on how to setup a `preact.config.js` to be able to use `react-router` ("react-router-dom": "^5.3.0"). Everything else works fine, but my app relies on react-router for nested tab navigation on certain pages.

Comment: Why do you think you need to setup any configuration to use `react-router-dom`? Just import the library and use it. Or are you seeing errors?

Comment: I was able to get `react-couter-dom` to work locally, but when running `yarn build` and then trying to run the app from the `/build` directory with http-server, accessing a nested tab, it can't find the route.

Comment: Any reason you're not using the built-in `serve` from the template? You've more than likely just set up your server incorrectly, but without you showing any code, we can only guess.

Comment: Used to the `create-react-app` way of doing it. Ran `yarn build` and then `yarn serve`, which directed me to `http://localhost:8080/`, but nothing rendered.

Comment: You need to provide a full example, this isn't enough information to go on. `preact-cli` templates ship with a `serve` command that uses `sirv-cli` and should set you up just fine. If something isn't working, we need to see code.